# Should I put a BackgroundWorker inside a Singleton?

Tags: c#, multithreading, singleton, backgroundworker

I have an application that takes a `Wireshark` capture file and feeds it (all the containing packets) into a network adapter.

Currently my application is a big mess - countless global variables & every task opened within a seperate `BackgroundWorker` instance etc...

To clarify - the purpose of using `BackgroundWorker`s here (more specifically the `DoWork`, `RunWorkerCompleted` events and the `WorkerReportsProgress` property) is to prevent the packet feeding operations from freezing my UI. To stop an operation, I need access to these workes - for now, global variables are used to achieve this.

So the question is - should I place my `BackgroundWorker` objects inside a `Singleton`-type class and then call this object when necessary?

Comment: Objects can have references to other objects. A singleton is nothing "magical" it's just an object that has only one instance.

Comment: So maybe it's better for me to create new class and put my Backgroundworker as a static member ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From  a technical point of view  is possible,  after all  the singleton pattern is a design pattern that restricts the instantiation of a class to one object 
you can  try something like this

```
  public class  BackWorkerSingleton
{
    private BackgroundWorker _backgroundWorker; 
    private static  readonly  object myLock = new object();
    private static  BackWorkerSingleton  _backWorkerSingleton =  new BackWorkerSingleton();

    public delegate  void  ReportProgressEventHandler(object sender,MyEventsArgs e);

    public event ReportProgressEventHandler ReportProgress = delegate{ };  

    private BackWorkerSingleton()
    {
        _backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        _backgroundWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(_backgroundWorker_DoWork);
        _backgroundWorker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(_backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged);

    }

    void _backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.ReportProgress( this, new MyEventsArgs(){Progress = e.ProgressPercentage});
    }

    void _backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // do your work here 
    }
    public void StartTheJob()
    {
        _backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
    public static  BackWorkerSingleton Worker
    {
        get
        {
            lock (myLock)
            {
                if (_backWorkerSingleton == null)
                {
                    _backWorkerSingleton = new BackWorkerSingleton();
                }
            }
            return _backWorkerSingleton;  
        }
    }


}

class MyEventsArgs:EventArgs
{
    public int Progress { get; set;  }
}
```

and here the report progress

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BackWorkerSingleton.Worker.ReportProgress += new BackWorkerSingleton.ReportProgressEventHandler(Worker_ReportProgress);
        }

        void Worker_ReportProgress(object sender, MyEventsArgs e)
        {

        }
```

and  call it like  this

```
BackWorkerSingleton.Worker.StartJob()
```

Comment: With this i can put my WorkerReportsProgress in my main form ? (update my UI)

Comment: yes surely you  can  take a look at the updated answer